# How to access the nodes using XML::LibXML in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, cpan

I have a XML data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/1307466/plain/):

What I want to do is to simply extract
the publication year from the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<pre> 
    <PubmedArticle>
        <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="In-Data-Review">
            <PMID Version="1">23853691</PMID>
            <DateCreated>
                <Year>2013</Year>
                <Month>07</Month>
                <Day>15</Day>
            </DateCreated>
            <Article PubModel="Electronic-Print">
                <Journal>
                    <ISSN IssnType="Electronic">1932-6203</ISSN>
                    <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Internet">
                        <Volume>8</Volume>
                        <Issue>5</Issue>
                        <PubDate>
                            <Year>2013</Year>
                        </PubDate>
...
</pre>
```

But why the following code Perl of mine failed to access the year "2013"?

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML 1.70;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $xmlfilename = "myfile.xml"; 
# obtained from http://dpaste.com/1307466/plain/

my $doc = $parser->parse_file( $xmlfilename );

foreach my $art ( $doc->findnodes('/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate') ) {
        my ($year) = $art->findnodes('./Year');
        print Dumper $year->to_literal ;

 }
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the `pre` root element.

Change

```
/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate
```

to

```
/pre/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Journal/JournalIssue/PubDate
```